# MassTransit mongodb saga timestamp

Tags: mongodb, masstransit

[C# program screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38K5v.png)

```
public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
```

[MongoDb screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpUzy.png)

```
    "Timestamp" : [
        637413725154206568,
        480
    ]
```

I am not sure how the masstransit saving this timestamp into mongodb. How can I convert it to a normal human readable datetime using **mongodb query**?

Comment: What is the property type in the class you're saving to MongoDB? You may want to find out how the MongoDB driver converts the property to BSON.

Comment: Yeah, MassTransit does nothing with that at all. Saga state is defined by you and it's up to you to decorate with BSON attributes or convert it accordingly.

Comment: the property type is DateTimeOffset